# How to determine the device name of a USB connected printer

Tags: macos, usb, printing

I'm trying to solve a printer issue and I'm attemting to send a text file via Ghostscript to a locally attached USB printer.  To do this, I need the device name (`/dev/<someidentifer>`).  How do I determine what that device identifier is?

The command I'm trying to issue is:

```
cat file.txt | gs -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=gdi \
-sPAPERSIZE=letter -r600 -sOutputFile=- - | cat /dev/**SOMEUSBIDENTIFER**
```

How can I find out what `/dev/**SOMEUSBIDENTIFER**` is?

*Please note:  I'm looking for the procedure to determine this as I don't have the actual printer to test.  All my current printers are networked and the last time I dealt with locally attached printers, parallel ports (Centronics) were all the rage (`/dev/lp0`)*.

Comment: Can't you just use `lpr`? Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404894/is-the-question-mark-in-a-uri-a-delimiter might give a clue.

Comment: Yes, but I’m trying to do this via gs

Comment: I was more thinking about piping `gs` into `lpr -o raw`.

Comment: We don’t know if the printer works or if the Foomatic filter and PPD functions correctly so I need to do this directly to the device. `lp`  Doesn’t send the job to the printer. It fails every time.  I’m trying To force it to use the driver that’s supposed to work.

Comment: Are you sure USB printers manifest in the filesystem at all?

Comment: From what I understand, they should @bmike but I have no idea what they appear as in macOS, but in [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/printing-connections.htm) it would show up as `/dev/unpt0`