# How do I pass a printer URI to lpadmin?

Tags: usb, printing

I'm trying to connect an LexmarkE210 to a Mac. Running

```
sudo lpinfo -v | grep 210   # find LexmarkE210 URI
```

gives me `usb://Lexmark/E210?location=1a140000` as the URI for the printer.

The [.ppd driver](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=gdi&printer=Lexmark-E210&.submit=Generate%20PPD%20file&show=1&.cgifields=show&.cgifields=shortgui) was downloaded from openprinting.org

I first tried:

```
lpadmin -E -p "Lexmark-E210" -v "usb://Lexmark/E210?" -P "/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Lexmark-E210-gdi.ppd" -o printer-is-shared=false
```

then tried without the question mark:

```
lpadmin -E -p "Lexmark-E210" -v "usb://Lexmark/E210" -P "/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Lexmark-E210-gdi.ppd" -o printer-is-shared=false
```

to pass this to `lpadmin` (as described in
[Add an IP printer with command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275388/add-an-ip-printer-with-command-line/275394#275394))   The result in either case is:

[image]

but it didn't work. So how do I pass the URI to `lpadmin`?

A third attempt to install the printer (no ?) with `lpadmin` returned printer status with the error:

[image]

A resume command, sent through the Web UI will set the printer status to idle, however, the problem persists.

Comment: What is the actual question here, which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for the question: context is appended to the original posting

Comment: Please make questions stand on their own, it's harder to get good answers if people have to pull the details from several questions. Which variants of passing the usb URI  to `lpadmin` have you already tried, what was the result?

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for the guidance & suggestions to sharpen the question

Answer (score 2):

`?` is used in URIs for parameterization. Here it is enabling use of the `location=` which appears to be a port reference.

So, it would seem you're asking if you should drop it in your descriptor I would say yes.